# Align selected region in emacs

Tags: emacs

For example I write code

```
if Foo do
  # do something
end
```

And then, I paste in my code many lines.

```
if Foo do
  # do something
# do something
# do something
# do something
# do something
end
```

How I can fast align added lines?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you want to align automatically on insert, or you want to align it later? For later you can use `indent-region` function (bound to `C-M-\`). For automatic align on insert you can use [following recipe](https://github.com/alexott/emacs-configs/blob/master/rc/emacs-rc-prog-misc.el) (I don't remember where I took it, so I'll refer to my config) - see lines 45-66. You will need to add more modes to `yank-indent-modes`, but concrete mode should provide working indent function.

Comment: @Alex I believe I wrote that code. :)  I'm glad someone finds it useful.  Likely original source: http://trey-jackson.blogspot.com/2008/03/emacs-tip-15-indent-yanked-code.html